# Subprocess.Popen wait untill the child finish

Tags: python, ubuntu, webserver, subprocess

I am developing a web tool based on CGI, Apache2, python (2.76). The web server is on Ubuntu virtual machine. After users submit a job, I want the server return a web page immediately, showing the link to the upcoming results. Because the calculation will take some time, so I used Subprocess.Popen to call a function, which do all calculation. Below show the flow of my codes. I tested on my own (Mac) computer, it can return a web page immediately, before the calculation finish. But on the Ubuntu virtual machine, it return the page untill the calculation finish. Doesn't Subprocess.Popen work on Ubuntu?

```
Main()
   preprocess 
   return_a_wen_page
   Subprocess.Popen(function_do_calculation)
```

Comment: why do you use cgi? have you considered something like mod_wsgi + flask?

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.Popen` works on Ubuntu. The issue might be that you are calling it from Apache.
You could try to redirect the standard streams:

```
with open(os.devnull, 'r+b', 0) as DEVNULL:
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL,
                     close_fds=True)
```

If it doesn't help, add also `preexec_fn=os.setsid` (`start_new_session=True` analog). Or just send a message ((unix) socket, named pipe) to independently running daemon on the machine that can call `subprocess.Popen` freely instead of the cgi script (consider if something like [`celery`](http://www.celeryproject.org/) may streamline it for you).

Answer (score 0):

It's the first time for me to do a web application, I don't know mod_wsgi.

```
with open(os.devnull, 'r+b', 0) as DEVNULL:
      subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL,close_fds=True)
```